# How to access Cloud Composer system files

Tags: environment-variables, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am working on a migration task from an on-premise system to a cloud composer, the thing is that Cloud composer is a fully managed version of airflow which restrict access to file systems behind, actually on my on-premise system I have a lot of environment variables for some paths we're saving them like `/opt/application/folder_1/subfolder_2/...`.

When looking at the Cloud composer documentation, they said that you can access and save your data on the *data* folder which is mapped by `/home/airflow/gcs/data/` which implies that in case I move forward that mapping, I will be supposed to change my env variables values to something like : `/home/airflow/gcs/data/application/folder_1/folder_2` things that could be a bit painful, knowing that I'm running many bash scripts that rely on those values.

Is there any approach to solve such problem ?

Comment: Let me understand you correctly, you wish to access an on prem fileshare from the DAG running on GKE cluster by trying to mount them to the GKE node?
In GKE, in order for the PODs to have access to mount points, the persistent volume claim and persistent volume are used.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to migrate from an on-premise workload automation called to cloud composer, the thing is that the on-premise tool was running on the top of a VM that had some env variables used by some bash scripts that needed to be executed, now when I moved to composer I don't see how can I set those env variables based on my system files like `/opt/...` since the processing is separated from the orchestration.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify your env variables during Composer creation/update process [1]. These vars are then stored in the YAML files that create the GKE cluster where Composer is hosted. If you SSH into a VM running the Composer GKE cluster, then enter one of the worker containers and run `env`, you can see the env variables you specified.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/managing/environment-variables